# OSX Mountain Lion PCL Point Cloud Library compile error (symbols not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: macos, cmake, osx-mountain-lion, x86-64, point-cloud-library

I'm getting the compile error shown below when trying to run `make` on my PCL build.

All the dependencies have been installed, but I'm wondering whether there were additional install constraints that weren't specified on the [installation page](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_macosx.php).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

```
[ 57%] Building CXX objectsurface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/src/3rdparty/poisson4/marching_cubes_poisson.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_surface.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_qh_prepare_output", referenced from:
     pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZ>::performReconstruction2D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&,    std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
        pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZ>::performReconstruction3D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&,    std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
     pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZI>::performReconstruction2D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>&,    std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
  pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZI>::performReconstruction3D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>&, std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
  pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZL>::performReconstruction2D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>&, std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
  pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZL>::performReconstruction3D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>&, std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
  pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::performReconstruction2D(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>&, std::vector<pcl::Vertices, std::allocator<pcl::Vertices> >&, bool) in convex_hull.cpp.o
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_surface.1.7.1.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [surface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I should add this is compiling the library itself, not a project that uses it.

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you sure that you have installed the appropriate (whichever that is) version of QHull? The linker can't find a symbol from that library.

Comment: QHull was installed from an updated MacPorts so I assume was the latest version. I've now managed to install the library by switching to HomeBrew.